# Create table with JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

I want create table with JSON using Javascript.

## 1. I create json API url (http://sample.com/getAllItems)

it return json data like this;

```
[{"ID":1,"NAME":"Tester","DEPARTMENT":"Dev","TITLE":"sample title","CONTENTS":"sample content","TYPE":0,"IMPORTANCE":"0","CREATED_AT":"2017-04-26 14:55:39","UPDATED_AT":"2017-04-27 00:00:00"},{"ID":4,"NAME":"","DEPARTMENT":"","TITLE":"smaple title2","CONTENTS":"sample content2","TYPE":null,"CREATED_AT":"2017-05-01 11:44:44","UPDATED_AT":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}]
```

## 2. I want make table with json data so..

```
    var apiURL = '/getAllItems'; 
    var data= [];  
    var option = [
        {field:"ID",width:10},
        {field:"TITLE", width:160},
        {field:"CONTENTS", width:420}
    ];

    $.getJSON(apiURL, function ( datas ) {
        $.each( datas, function( key, val ){
            data.push( val );
        });
    });

    window.onload = function() {
        var itemTable = $("#itemTable"); 
        var makeTable = $("<table>").appendTo(itemTable); 
        makeTable.css({"border-collapse": "collapse", "border": "1px #CCC solid"});

        $.each( data, function( index, row) {
            var makeTr = $("<tr>").appendTo(makeTable);
            console.log("index : "+index);
            console.log("row : "+ row);

            $.each( option, function( i, fieldInfo ) {
                var makeTd = $("<td>").appendTo(makeTr);
                console.log("Index : "+index);
                console.log("Row : "+row);
                console.log( "i : "+i);
                console.log( "fieldInfo : "+fieldInfo);
                console.log( "fieldInfo.field : "+fieldInfo.field);
                console.log( "Row[Field] : "+row[fieldInfo.field]);

                makeTd.html( row[fieldInfo.field]);
                makeTd.css({"width": fieldInfo.width+"px", "border": "1px #CCC solid"});
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```

and

it return

```
--------------------------------------
1   | sample title | sample content
--------------------------------------
2   | sample title2| sample content2
----------------------------------------
```

I want using header cell but I can't.. how can I get like this table?

```
--------------------------------------
ID  | Title        | Content
--------------------------------------
1   | sample title | sample content
--------------------------------------
2   | sample title2| sample content2
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you can try.. hope explanation make sense..if anything you wont get please go ahead and comment... :D

```js
var apiURL = '/getAllItems'; 
    var data= [];  
    var option = [
        {field:"ID",width:10},
        {field:"TITLE", width:160},
        {field:"CONTENTS", width:420}
    ];

//commented your Ajax for testing.

    /*$.getJSON(apiURL, function ( datas ) {
        $.each( datas, function( key, val ){
            data.push( val );
        });
    });
*/

//get the data varable set

data = [{"ID":1,"NAME":"Tester","DEPARTMENT":"Dev","TITLE":"sample title","CONTENTS":"sample content","TYPE":0,"IMPORTANCE":"0","CREATED_AT":"2017-04-26 14:55:39","UPDATED_AT":"2017-04-27 00:00:00"},{"ID":2,"NAME":"","DEPARTMENT":"","TITLE":"smaple title2","CONTENTS":"sample content2","TYPE":null,"CREATED_AT":"2017-05-01 11:44:44","UPDATED_AT":"0000-00-00 00:00:00"}];


//begin creating table on load.
window.onload = function() {
        
        //create table element.
        var makeTable = $("<table>");
        //append table to existing div here it have class "test".
        $(".test").append($(makeTable));
        //append first row for headings.
        $(makeTable).append($("<tr>"));
        
        //append all heading in loop.
        $.each(option,function(i,dt){
            //simply find first tr and append td with content to it.
            $(makeTable).find("tr").append("<td>"+dt["field"]+"</td>");
        });
    
      // start appending data.
      $.each(data,function(i,row){
        //find tbody in table and add tr to it.
           var nrow = $(makeTable).find('tbody').append("<tr>"); 
       //for each options find its value in data and append to newly created tr above.
           $.each(option,function(j,dt){
              // this is actually what you want..  
              $(nrow).append("<td>"+row[dt["field"]]+"</td>");
            });
       });
    }

    //done.
```

```css
table,td
{
border: 1px #CCC solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">
</div>
```

Comment: downvoters..please consider adding reason or comments..just honking the down-button wont gonna add anything in your value...

Comment: wow, it works! Thank you for your kindness! It's very useful example.
.. I vote this answer is useful but it says "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." .. I'm sorry to someone vote not useful, but your answer is best solution to me. thank you.

Comment: thats fine..still i guess if it solves your problem you can mark it as answer rest happy to help...we are here to help,share and grow....cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
var makeTh = $("<th>").appendTo(makeTable);
$.each(option, function (index, row) {
    var makeTd = $("<td>").append(makeTh);
    makeTd.css({width, row['width']}).html(row['field']);
});
```

try to add code upon the first `$.each`.

Comment: I think it's the logical solution but it doesn't work.. I can't understand why (T_T)

Comment: just loop the `option` variable to render the `th` tag.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the row for header before your loop is starting

```
 var apiURL = '/getAllItems'; 
    var data= [];  
    var option = [
        {field:"ID",width:10},
        {field:"TITLE", width:160},
        {field:"CONTENTS", width:420}
    ];

    $.getJSON(apiURL, function ( datas ) {
        $.each( datas, function( key, val ){
            data.push( val );
        });
    });

    window.onload = function() {
        var itemTable = $("#itemTable"); 
        var makeTable = $("<table>").appendTo(itemTable); 
        var head='<tr><th>ID</th><th>TITLE</th><th>CONTENT</th></tr>';
        makeTable.css({"border-collapse": "collapse", "border": "1px #CCC solid"});
          $(head).appendTo(makeTable);
        $.each( data, function( index, row) {
            var makeTr = $("<tr>").appendTo(makeTable);
            console.log("index : "+index);
            console.log("row : "+ row);

            $.each( option, function( i, fieldInfo ) {
                var makeTd = $("<td>").appendTo(makeTr);
                console.log("Index : "+index);
                console.log("Row : "+row);
                console.log( "i : "+i);
                console.log( "fieldInfo : "+fieldInfo);
                console.log( "fieldInfo.field : "+fieldInfo.field);
                console.log( "Row[Field] : "+row[fieldInfo.field]);

                makeTd.html( row[fieldInfo.field]);
                makeTd.css({"width": fieldInfo.width+"px", "border": "1px #CCC solid"});
            });
        });
    }

</script>
```